# How can I abort the call to sigwaitinfo?

Tags: c++, linux, signals

### Background

My objective is to handle certain signals on a dedicated thread rather than to have them handled on any of the threads that happen to be running in my process when the signal is raised.

I am doing this as follows (in this example, for signal 16 only):

On the main thread, before any other threads are started (error handling ommited)

```
sigset_t sigset;
sigaddset(&sigset, 16);
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, nullptr);
```

Then I create a thread that waits for those signals (only 16 in this example):

```
std::thread _thread = std::thread([&]()
{
   int ret = sigwaitinfo(&sigset, nullptr);
   if (ret == 16)
   {
       // handle signal 16
   }
});
```

This works well.

### Problem

However, I would like to be able to cancel the call to sigwaitinfo when needed.

### Two Inadequate Solutions

I have tried two solutions, but neither are adequate:

### 1. Polling

One option (that works) is not to use sigwaitinfo but rather to use sigtimedwait which accepts a timeout argument.
This allows me to use polling and to cancel when the call next returns and some cancel flag is set.
The code in the thread then looks like this:

```
std::atomic<bool> _cancel (false);
std::thread _thread = std::thread([&]()
{
    timespec _timespec {0, 1}; // 1 second
    int ret = sigtimedwait(&sigset, nullptr, _timespec);
    if (_cancel) 
    {
        return;
    }
    if (ret == 16)
    {
        // handle signal 16
    }
});
```

In order to cancel, I only need to set the _cancel flag in the main thread.
The problem with this solution, is that polling incurs the typical trade-off between responsiveness (of the cancellation) and the amount of busy work done checking the cancellation flag.

### 2. raise()/sigqueue()/kill()

In this solution I add to the signal mask a dedicated signal, for instance SIGUSR1 with the following call:

```
sigset_t sigset;
sigaddset(&sigset, 16);
sigaddset(&sigset, SIGUSR1); // <-- added call here
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, nullptr);
```

Then when I need to cancel the call to sigwaitinfo I set a cancel flag and call raise(SIGUSR1)

The code in the thread then looks like this:

```
std::atomic<bool> _cancel (false);
std::thread _thread = std::thread([&]()
{
   int ret = sigwaitinfo(&sigset, nullptr);
   if (_cancel) // <-- now check _cancel flag before handling signal
   {
       return;
   }
   if (ret == 16)
   {
       // handle signal 16
   }
});
```

The cancellation is now done as follows:

```
_cancel = true; // <-- set the flag before raising the signal
raise(SIGUSR1);
```

The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work, because the call to raise() does not cause sigwaitinfo to return in the dedicated thread. I believe that according to the documentation it will only raise the signal in the executing thread itself.
sigqueue() and kill() also do not work.

### Summary

Is there a way to cause sigwaitinfo to return prematurely, without requiring a loop in which calls to sigtimedwait are called with a timeout?

Comment: *Why* do you believe the issue with `raise()` to also affect `kill()` or `sigqueue()`?

Comment: I did try sigqueue and the same issue occurred. I admit I did not try kill, but the documentation of raise says that it is the equivalent of calling kill(getpid(), sig).
Am I wrong?

Comment: In a multithreaded process, yes. As you see, the target is the entire process, so if only one thread in that process has the signal unblocked, then that thread should receive the signal, regardless of whether it was the sender. However, the same *should* be true of `sigqeue()`, so there is probably another bug in your program. For example: did you remember that `sigwaitinfo()` modifies the sigset?

Comment: I will try this again. But I would like to emphasize that when I tested this I had only one thread (other than the dedicated polling thread), Moreover, even when there will be more threads, they will be created only after the call to sigprocmask() so I believe I am correct in assuming that the blocked signals will be blocked in all threads.
How does sigwaitinfo() modify the sigset? I did not find that ...

Comment: man sigwaitinfo: `sigwaitinfo() removes the signal from the set of pending signals and returns
       the signal number as its function result.  If the info argument is not NULL,
       then the buffer that it points to is used to return a structure of type sig‐
       info_t (see sigaction(2)) containing information about the signal.`

Comment: Ah, that doesnt mean that the sig is removed from the sigset - only that the sig is removed from the set of pending signals.

Comment: Update. My test with raise() and kill() are not proof that it does not work because another problem had masked the result of the test.
I am running this test in a secure environment which does not give me permission to call raise or kill.

Comment: But this still leaves solution 2 inadequate because it requires elevated permissions to be able to abort the call to sigwaitinfo()

Comment: Which part of sending a signal to the own process do you believe to require elevated permissions?

Comment: Why the cancel-flag stuff? Why not just test `sigwaitinfo()` for having returned `-1`?

Comment: Why do you mark a question with specific C++ details as C?  In C in Linux, there are two trivial solutions, but I suspect neither will not work for the code shown here (because of how C++ runtime differs from the C hosted environment).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pthread_kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) to send a signal to a specific thread.

E.g., instead of `raise(SIGUSR1);` do:

```
if(int rc = ::pthread_kill(_thread.native_handle(), SIGUSR1))
    // Handle pthread_kill error.
```

Comment: I was looking for a more cooperative way to achieve this. I don't think killing a thread is advisable if it can be avoided.

Comment: @DavidSackstein `pthread_kill` sends a signal to a thread. You probably confuse it with `pthread_cancel`.

Comment: You are right. I did mistake this. But still, in my system I did not have permissions to call raise() so I suspect that pthread_kill would also be blocked. I think that the solution I found is cleaner, because it uses a different channel for cancellation.

Comment: @DavidSackstein Yep, an event loop is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found.

1. Instead of waiting with sigtimedwait, use signalfd to get a file descriptor that represents the signals to be handled. (sigprocmask or similar need to be called first as with the solution presented in the question).
2. Call eventfd to return an "event" file descriptor.
3. Call poll wait on both file descriptors. This blocks. Do so in a loop.
4. Signal cancellation by writing to the event file descriptor on a different thread.
5. When poll returns check which file descriptor was signaled by checking the revents fields.
6. If the event file descriptor was signaled break from the loop.
7. Else (the signalfd descriptor was signaled) read the signal description and handle the signal by calling the handler. Then loop around calling poll again.

---

I have verified that this solution is reliable.
More detailed information can be found in the documentation for:
`signalfd`,`eventfd` and `poll`